# Absolute positioned child vs. border

Tags: css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="xoxo">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="xo">Destination</label>
            <input class="animatedinput" type="text" id="xo" />
            <div class="jabudunapoveda">Here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here css:

```
.animatedinput {
    padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.field {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;

}
label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 2em;
    top: 0;
    left: 1.5em;
    z-index: 4;
}
.jabudunapoveda {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.xoxo {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto 4em;
    z-index: 2;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

- Div with class jabudunapoveda must be absolute positioned
- Why red border over div with class .field has only 0px height?
- Height of .field is unknown.

Goal is make div with class .field 100% height so red border going to end at the bottom of jabudunapoveda div.

here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKxLxk?editors=1100)

Comment: why absolute ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBmVXj?editors=1100 if absolute is an absolute need, then maybe set only the parent in absolute; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNJzwQ?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

If You change .field to this, its working

```
.field {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;

}
```

div field, must have height greater than height of .jabudunapoveda